# SQL query needs improvement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to get `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` of `STUDENT`, which have started after course after year 2010 and it's average grade from all disciplines is above 5.50. Year is integer(4) Grades props are - null (not finished yet), 0 (not being on exam) and 2,3,4,5,6.

Database: Oracle

What am I trying is: for each student with `YEARSATART` greater than 2010, get average of his grades, except those which are nulls or zeros.

Code I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
FROM PERSON  
JOIN STUDENT ON PERSON.PERSONID = STUDENT.STUDENTID 
JOIN CLASSSTUDENT ON STUDENT.STUDENTID = CLASSSTUDENT.STUDENTID
WHERE STUDENT.YEARSTART > 2010
  AND (SELECT AVG(FINALGRADE) 
       FROM CLASSSTUDENT
       WHERE FINALGRADE IS NOT NULL
         AND FINALGRADE > 1) >= 4.50;
```

I guess my query is wrong because I see not proper results. Do you have any ideas of improvements / fixes? Where could be my mistake? I got feeling that I get average from all grades, not for each student separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing a where on your subselect.  You need to filter on classstudent where the StudentID=Student.StudentID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PERSON  
JOIN STUDENT ON PERSON.PERSONID = STUDENT.STUDENTID 
JOIN CLASSSTUDENT ON STUDENT.STUDENTID = CLASSSTUDENT.STUDENTID
WHERE STUDENT.YEARSTART > 2010
AND (SELECT AVG(FINALGRADE) 
    FROM CLASSSTUDENT
    WHERE FINALGRADE IS NOT NULL 
    AND FINALGRADE > 1
    AND STUDENTID=STUDENT.STUDENTID) >= 4.50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join nested query to external one, is preferable to set `alias` to each table to allow disambiguation. Also you don't need `CLASSSTUDENT` on main query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
FROM PERSON  
JOIN STUDENT S ON PERSON.PERSONID = S.STUDENTID 
WHERE STUDENT.YEARSTART > 2010
AND (SELECT AVG(FINALGRADE) 
        FROM CLASSSTUDENT C
        WHERE C.STUDENTID = S.STUDENTID
        AND FINALGRADE > 1) >= 4.50;
```

Also not null, on nested query, is not needed because aggregation function don't compute null values.

Comment: Sorry, What is not proper?